# get sub categories from category id Magento

Tags: magento

i am trying to get sub-categories from category id. 
but looking for more optimized code as the database vast records and cannot afford to load whole category.

i have tried below codes they are working on localhost but as my server has huge data it doesn't work there

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(13);
$subcats = $cat->getChildrenCategories();

//AND

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat_id);
```

please help

Comment: Which data do you need whole category data is to much? Already enabled flat category tables?

Comment: flat is already enabled.. i am trying to get id of product which are in that particular category..

Comment: i want to get subcategories and i was looking for alternative method for doing that. because further when i try to get products for respective subcategories i get server 503 error(when the subcategory list is lengthy), looking for something which is lightweight

Comment: `$cat->getChildrenCategories();` returns an category collection. How do you process it's data? Using collections is a bit slower than direct sql queries but is the general approach in magento and should be ok. If you just need it to get associated products you could just select id fields an filter a product collection by that ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
<?php 
$root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(13); 
$subCat = explode(',',$root->getChildren()); 

$collection  = $root
             ->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
             ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $subCat) );

foreach($collection as $catname){
echo $catname->getName();
}
?>
```